# How to make allowMultiQueries in INFORMIX sql queries

Tags: jdbc, informix

I have a question about supporting allowMultiQueries in INFORMIX sql queries
I know a way for MySQL:

```
jdbc:mysql://10.242.182.152:3306/db?allowMultiQueries=true
```

Is there a way for INFORMIX ?

Comment: AFAIK such parameter don't exists at Informix. You can check the [Informix JDBC manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/jdbc.htm) to check how work with it...

Answer (score 1):

In Informix it is standard to use multiple `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` statements in one `execute()` call. It works with ODBC and JDBC drivers I use. I don't know if you can mix it with SELECT statements, but my eyes hurts when I see JDBC code that works with MySQL mixture of INSERT and SELECT. For such complicated things I would use stored function.

PS I don't like this feature while it is easier to write code that can be attacked by SQL injection.